# How to implement a best-first search in Haskell?

Tags: haskell

Is there a way to do a best-first search efficiently in Haskell? I want to maintain a dynamic tree. I have a heuristic function which can compute a number for each node and a successor function which will return a list of children of a node.

At every step, I want to take the leaf-node with the best heuristic and replace it with its children. This process is repeated until I get a node which is 'good enough'.

For this, I need to maintain a priority queue of the leaves. But is there a way by which I can go from a leaf in the priority queue to its position in the tree efficiently so that I can modify the tree?

Comment: Zippers or Prisms.  Although if you make the tree actually mutable (e.g. composed of a bunch of IORefs), they might not help.

Comment: I am not familiar with Prisms. As for Zippers, are they applicable here, as I would need to focus on all the leaves simultaneously?

Answer (score 6):

One possible answer is to use Haskell's sneakiest form of mutability: *laziness*. If you lazily generate the *entire* tree (even if it's *infinite*) then repeatedly view different points in the tree according to your priority queue then you will only ever produce as much of the tree as is needed to perform your best-first search.

You'll still pay for repeated traversals of the lower branches of the tree, but perhaps you can change the structure of your search somehow to do better.

Comment: Are you suggesting a knot-tieing approach?

Comment: There's potential, but I'd want to learn more about the exact algorithm first. Even without knot tying, exploiting laziness is a good idea.

Answer (score 2):

You shouldn't need an explicit tree for a best first search. Just the priority queue should do. Make the nodes of the queue carry as much context as necessary to compute the successor nodes and cost function. If you really need the tree, then as others have said, zippers are the way to go. You'd keep zippers in your priority queue rather than just tree nodes. Since the priority queue holds all the leaves, you shouldn't need to modify a shared tree.

Comment: exactly. each step is simply `step (x:xs) | goodEnuf x = x | otherwise = merge (prioritized (children x)) xs`.

Comment: But the problem here is once a leaf is "modified", the change should be propagated to all the other nodes, which would be an expensive operation.

Answer (score 1):

Check out the [weighted-search](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/weighted-search) package, which implements a priority search monad.  It allows you to express the solutions you want, adding `weight` along the way to indicate when you know that a solution has increased in expense, and the package will find the least-weight solutions first.  In your case, create the whole tree (possibly infinite) you want to search, and then use weighted-search to construct all the paths through that tree and give weights to them. Then you will get the least-weight paths first.